# Provide the python code: Identify when the elements of a list exchanged positions in groups of three

Tags: python, list, vertices

Syppose I have a list that represents the vertices of a graph.

```
 lista = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

I take the list and I compute the automorphism group to the vertices. This returns me a new list where my vertices are exchanged in groups of three. The output list is the following:

```
 output = [0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,6,10,11,9,13,14,12,16,17,15,19,20,18]
```

If you hand-analyse the list you can identify that the elements an exchanged in groups of three. Here in our example,

```
changed_elements = [[7,8,6],[10,11,9],[13,14,12],[16,17,15],[19,20,18]]
```

I would like the python code or the pseudocode of how to identify and group together the three elements that are exchanged together

Comment: You can start by writing some codes and explaining about the problems with your code so that we can understand the problem and even the question.

Comment: My question it is just that. I have a list of vertices where I perform the automorphism group and the output is the output list. In the change_elements it is my identification (by looking through the list without code) that for example the elements [7,8,6] changed together. Element 7 is in the position where six was, element 8 is in the position of where 7 was and element 6 is at the position where 8 was. I want to identify this changes using python. I can currently do this when they are changed in groups of two (when 7 for example is at the 6th position and 6 is at the seventh position)

Comment: should lista start with a 0?

Comment: Yes, I am so sorry  I have forgotten it, just noticed

Comment: okay I am sorry is my very first question in here!

Comment: Please edit your comment into the actual question so that people have context on what you're trying to do, rather than it being in a comment.

Comment: I vaguely remember a combinatorics problem similar to this, but I can't find anything about it online after some brief research. It looks as though non-contiguous substrings of your input are forming cyclic derangements under your permutation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def identify_cycles(l1, l2):
    d1 = {val: idx for idx, val in enumerate(l1)} 
    # This assumes unique values in input l1, but I think the question does too
    out = []
    for idx, val in enumerate(l1):
        curr = l2[idx]
        if curr == val or any(val in s for s in out):
            continue # If this value doesn't move, or we've seen this cycle, then skip
        x = set([val]) # Otherwise, we're at the start of a new cycle
        while curr != val:
            x.add(curr) # The value at this index in l2 is also in this cycle
            curr = l2[d1[curr]] 
            # The next value in the cycle will be in l2 at the index that curr is at in l1
        out.append(x)
    return out

print(identify_cycles(lista, output))
# [{8, 6, 7}, {9, 10, 11}, {12, 13, 14}, {16, 17, 15}, {18, 19, 20}]
```

I believe the above should be able to identify cycles of any length > 1.